# *NIX read()/write(): Are they re-entrant?

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

What would happen if an interrupt/thread preempts in middle of execution of  `read(fd,buff,size)` or `write(fd,buff,size)` functions and then it returns to where it was in `read()/write()`? 
Can we assume it will continue reading or writing to the file descriptor without loss of data and order?

Assume there is no shared variables to worry about synchronization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` and `write` are system calls, so from the point of view of user-space, they are "atomic" -- there's no way for an interrupt or thread to preempt them "in the middle" of execution.  Any signal will be delivered after the system call completes -- if it is an interrupting signal it may cause a "short" read or write (fewer bytes read or written than expected) or an `EINTR` error value, in which case the user-level program (when it resumes after the interrupt and system call) will need to deal with that.

Comment: Interesting...so even if the system call is blocking for some reason, it wouldn't be preempted by any thread? Wouldn't that be bad?

Comment: If its blocking and a signal occurs, then it will be interrupted and return EINTR -- which may then be automatically handled by the standard library, redoing the system call.  A thread in a system call that is blocked does not use a CPU, so the OS will schedule some other thread or process on that CPU.

Comment: So even OS schedules some thread, upon return, it continues where it was safely. Thanks.